# How to give one variant a specific type in generic class constructor?

Tags: java, generics, constructor

This is what I've written:

```
public class LinkedListDeque<Whatever> {
    private class Node {
        private Whatever item;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        private Node(Whatever i, Node p, Node n) {
            item = i;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    private Node sentinel;
    private int size;

    /** Creates an empty Deque. */
    public LinkedListDeque() {
        sentinel = new Node(null, sentinel, sentinel);
        size = 0;
    }
}
```

Now I want to replace the `null` in the fourth row from the bottom with something like `Integer 1` then my IDE (`Intellij`) told me that `',' or ')' expected`.

**Here is the question:**

I want to set `sentinel.item` `equals to 1` in this constructor, is that possible?

Take a step back, are there ant other codes can safely replace the code `null`?

Comment: you need first create the object of Whatever or pass a value that matches the hierarchy of Whatever.

is that a random name you have given or is this some reference in your program. If you really mean `WhatEver` you should use `Object`

Comment: No, `Whatever` is fine - it's a type parameter.  Although it's normal to use single letters for type parameters, especially `T` or `E`, you don't have to; so `Whatever` is OK.  The part that's not OK is assuming that `1` can be a `Whatever`.  If you're making a list of `String`s, for example, it doesn't make sense to have `1` in there, because `1` is not a `String`.

Comment: `null` is a perfectly acceptable sentinel.

Comment: *FYI:* When `sentinel = new Node(null, sentinel, sentinel)` is executed, the two `sentinel` parameters are `null`, so you might as well have written `sentinel = new Node(null, null, null)`. You have to either set `next` and `prev` to `sentinel` *after* the constructor returns, or create a special constructor that sets them to `this` *inside* the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think your real problem is not correct implementation:

1. Your `LinkedListDeque` has `sentinel` node, i.e. head of the queue. Therefore, if queue is empty, then `size = 0` and `sentinel = null`;
2. When you add new item to your queue, you have to check either it is empty (i.e. `size = 0` or `sentinel = null`) or not. In case it is empty, just create new `Node`, otherwise add new node to the end of the queue;
3. According above, you should not change `Node.item`, i.e. it shuld be `final`: `private Whatever item`.

I think your class could look like this one *(this is just example)*:

```
public final class LinkedListDeque<Whatever> {

    private class Node {

        private final Whatever item;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        private Node(Whatever item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    private Node sentinel;
    private int size;

    public void add(Whatever item) {
        Node node = new Node(item);

        if (size != 0) {
            node.next = sentinel;
            sentinel.prev = node;
        }

        sentinel = node;
        size++;
    }

}
```